# rendering error; couldn't resolve @id/search_edit_frame

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I am having an error that says couldn't resolve **@id/search_edit_frame** I don't know why,
I tried the ***File>Invalidate Caches> Just Restart and restart*** android studio also tried to change the render version all of my supported api..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
      android:id="@+id/svSearch"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="25sp"
      android:textColor="@color/textDefault"
       myapp="@string/search_hint"
       myapp="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 and sure that it compiles **android.support.v7.widget(AppCompat)**

any help will be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: Strangely an app that has been using the v7 support SearchView for a week stopped rendering today with that error. Android Studio Bug? Resolved by switching to `android.widget.SearchView` instead (supported from API 11)

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
 <SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
    android:queryHint="Search"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

it should work

Comment: Your solution fixes the problem, but it's not ideal. The SearchView you provided is from android.widget, however the one @johnguild is using it's actually from android.support.v7.widget.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can search **@id/search_edit_frame** in all your xml file to check where it comes from.

Second, if you are sure that there is no **@id/search_edit_frame** in your xml, then you can try to delete all files in your Build folder.

Try to clean your project also.

Comment: would be please kindly tell which build folder should i empty.. also tried cleaning my project.

Comment: This seems to be a part of the abc_search_view.xml res file.